# GSM MQTT+CMT(SMS Reading)

Tags: c++, sms, mqtt, esp8266, sim800l

I'm working a code to pubsub over GSM SIM800L and ARDUINO MEGA.

I'm able to workout MQTT fine, using [ElementzOnline](https://gist.github.com/elementzonline) / [SIM800_MQTT](https://github.com/elementzonline/SIM800_MQTT/blob/master/GSM_MQTT_Arduino_Publish/GSM_MQTT.cpp) code.

I'm now having trouble to use MQTT alongside SMSReading (+CMT) and Call Receiving. I've made a RecSMS() to receive incoming messages, and it works fine as long as TCP Connection is not true, **The problem is: Once TCP/MQTT is connected, my RecSMS Function displays no more sms to Serial and calls can not be received**

This is Call Receiving, which is handled via RingPing....

```
void GSM_MQTT::receivecall(){
  HangUp=1;
  if(MQTT.TCP_Flag==true){disconnect();}
  delay(1000);
  SIMSerial.write("AT+CGATT=0\n");
  delay(1000);
  //SIMSerial.write("AT+CIPSHUT\n");
  modemStatus=0;
  SIMSerial.write("ATA\n");SIMSerial.write(26);Monitor("Incomig Call");
}
void GSM_MQTT::endcall(){if(HangUp==1){HangUp=0;SIMSerial.write("ATH\n");SIMSerial.write(26);Monitor("Call Ended");}}
```

This is RecSMS():

```
char inchar4;char inchar3;char inchar2;char inchar1;int times=0;
void RecSMS(char data){
  if(times==3){inchar4=data;times++;}
  if(times==2){inchar3=data;times++;}
  if(times==1){inchar2=data;times++;}
  if(times==0){inchar1=data;times++;}
  if(times>=4){
    inchar1=inchar2;inchar2=inchar3;inchar3=inchar4;inchar4=data;
    if((inchar1== '+') && (inchar2== 'C')&&(inchar3== 'M')&&(inchar4== 'T')){RcvdConf = 1;}
    if(RcvdConf == 1){
      if(data == '\n'){RcvdEnd++;}
      if(RcvdEnd == 3){RcvdEnd = 0;}
      RcvdMsg[count] = data;
      count++;
      if(RcvdEnd == 2){RcvdConf = 0;MsgLength = count-2;count= 0;}
      if(RcvdConf == 0){
        Serial.print("Mobile Number is: ");
        for(int x = 4;x < 18;x++){MsgMob[x-4] = RcvdMsg[x];Serial.print(MsgMob[x-4]);}
        Serial.println();
        Serial.print("Message Text: ");
        for(int x = 47; x < MsgLength; x++){MsgTxt[x-47] = RcvdMsg[x];Serial.print(MsgTxt[x-47]);}
        Serial.println();
        char RcvdMsg[200] = "";int RcvdConf = 0;int count = 0;int RcvdEnd = 0;char MsgMob[15];char MsgTxt[50];int MsgLength = 0;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

SerialEvent() is called every second...

```
void serialEvent(){
  while(Serial3.available()){
    char inChar=(char)Serial3.read();
    RecSMS(inChar);//<////////////////////////sms reading
    if(MQTT.TCP_Flag==false){
      if(MQTT.index<200){MQTT.inputString[MQTT.index++]=inChar;}
      if(inChar=='\n'){
        MQTT.inputString[MQTT.index]=0;stringComplete=true;Serial.print(MQTT.inputString);
        if(strstr(MQTT.inputString,MQTT.reply)!=NULL){
          MQTT.GSM_ReplyFlag=1;
          if(strstr(MQTT.inputString," INITIAL")!=0){MQTT.GSM_ReplyFlag=2;}
          else if(strstr(MQTT.inputString," START")!=0){MQTT.GSM_ReplyFlag=3;}
          else if(strstr(MQTT.inputString," IP CONFIG")!=0){_delay_us(10);MQTT.GSM_ReplyFlag=4;}
          else if(strstr(MQTT.inputString," GPRSACT")!=0){MQTT.GSM_ReplyFlag=4;}
          else if((strstr(MQTT.inputString," STATUS")!=0)||(strstr(MQTT.inputString,"TCP CLOSED")!=0)){MQTT.GSM_ReplyFlag=5;}
          else if(strstr(MQTT.inputString," TCP CONNECTING")!=0){MQTT.GSM_ReplyFlag=6;}
          else if((strstr(MQTT.inputString," CONNECT OK")!=0)||(strstr(MQTT.inputString,"CONNECT FAIL")!=NULL)||(strstr(MQTT.inputString,"PDP DEACT")!=0)){MQTT.GSM_ReplyFlag=7;}}
        else if(strstr(MQTT.inputString,"OK")!=NULL){GSM_Response=1;}
        else if(strstr(MQTT.inputString,"ERROR")!=NULL){GSM_Response=2;}
        else if(strstr(MQTT.inputString,".")!= NULL){GSM_Response=3;}
        else if(strstr(MQTT.inputString,"CONNECT FAIL")!=NULL){GSM_Response=5;}
        else if(strstr(MQTT.inputString,"CONNECT")!=NULL){GSM_Response=4;MQTT.TCP_Flag=true;MQTT.AutoConnect();MQTT.pingFlag=true;MQTT.tcpATerrorcount=0;Serial.println("MQTT.TCP_Flag=True");}
        else if(strstr(MQTT.inputString,"CLOSED")!=NULL){GSM_Response=4;MQTT.TCP_Flag=false;MQTT.MQTT_Flag=false;Serial.println("TCP_Flag=False");}
        MQTT.index=0;MQTT.inputString[0]=0;
      }
    }else{
      uint8_t ReceivedMessageType=(inChar/16) & 0x0F;uint8_t DUP=(inChar & DUP_Mask)/DUP_Mask;
      uint8_t QoS=(inChar & QoS_Mask)/QoS_Scale;uint8_t RETAIN=(inChar & RETAIN_Mask);
      if((ReceivedMessageType>=CONNECT)&&(ReceivedMessageType<=DISCONNECT)){
        bool NextLengthByte=true;MQTT.length=0;MQTT.lengthLocal=0;uint32_t multiplier=1;delay(2);char Cchar=inChar;
        while((NextLengthByte==true)&&(MQTT.TCP_Flag==true)){
          if(Serial3.available()){
            inChar=(char)Serial3.read();/*Serial.println(inChar, DEC);*/
            if(((((Cchar & 0xFF)=='C')&&((inChar & 0xFF)=='L'))||(((Cchar & 0xFF)=='+')&&((inChar & 0xFF)=='P')))&&(MQTT.length==0)){
              MQTT.index=0;MQTT.inputString[MQTT.index++]=Cchar;MQTT.inputString[MQTT.index++]=inChar;
              MQTT.TCP_Flag=false;MQTT.MQTT_Flag=false;MQTT.pingFlag=false;Serial.println("Disconnecting");
              Serial.println("MQTT.TCP_Flag=False (ln223)");
            }else{
              if((inChar&128)==128){MQTT.length+=(inChar&127)*multiplier;multiplier*=128;Serial.println("More");}
              else{NextLengthByte=false;MQTT.length+=(inChar&127)*multiplier;multiplier*=128;}
            }
          }
        }
        MQTT.lengthLocal=MQTT.length;/*Serial.println(MQTT.length);*/ 
        if(MQTT.TCP_Flag==true){
          MQTT.printMessageType(ReceivedMessageType);MQTT.index=0L;uint32_t a=0;
          while((MQTT.length-- > 0)&&(Serial3.available())){MQTT.inputString[uint32_t(MQTT.index++)]=(char)Serial3.read();delay(1);}
          /*Serial.println(" ");*/  
          if (ReceivedMessageType==CONNACK){
            MQTT.ConnectionAcknowledgement=MQTT.inputString[0]*256+MQTT.inputString[1];
            if(MQTT.ConnectionAcknowledgement==0){MQTT.MQTT_Flag=true;MQTT.OnConnect();}
            MQTT.printConnectAck(MQTT.ConnectionAcknowledgement); /*MQTT.OnConnect();*/
          }else if(ReceivedMessageType==PUBLISH){
            uint32_t TopicLength=(MQTT.inputString[0])*256+(MQTT.inputString[1]);Serial.print("Topic: '");MQTT.PublishIndex = 0;
            for(uint32_t iter=2;iter<TopicLength+2;iter++){Serial.print(MQTT.inputString[iter]);MQTT.Topic[MQTT.PublishIndex++]=MQTT.inputString[iter];}
            MQTT.Topic[MQTT.PublishIndex]=0;Serial.print("' Message: '");
            MQTT.TopicLength=MQTT.PublishIndex;MQTT.PublishIndex=0;uint32_t MessageSTART=TopicLength+2UL;int MessageID=0;
            if(QoS!=0){MessageSTART+=2;MessageID=MQTT.inputString[TopicLength+2UL]*256+MQTT.inputString[TopicLength+3UL];}
            for(uint32_t iter=(MessageSTART);iter<(MQTT.lengthLocal);iter++){Serial.print(MQTT.inputString[iter]);MQTT.Message[MQTT.PublishIndex++]=MQTT.inputString[iter];}
            MQTT.Message[MQTT.PublishIndex]=0;Serial.println("'");MQTT.MessageLength=MQTT.PublishIndex;
            if(QoS==1){MQTT.publishACK(MessageID);}else if(QoS==2){MQTT.publishREC(MessageID);}
            MQTT.OnMessage(MQTT.Topic,MQTT.TopicLength,MQTT.Message,MQTT.MessageLength);MQTT.MessageFlag=true;
          }else if(ReceivedMessageType==PUBREC){MQTT.publishREL(0,MQTT.inputString[0]*256+MQTT.inputString[1]);
            int MessageID=MQTT.inputString[0]*256+MQTT.inputString[1];
          }else if(ReceivedMessageType==PUBREL){MQTT.publishCOMP(MQTT.inputString[0]*256+MQTT.inputString[1]);
            int MessageID=MQTT.inputString[0]*256+MQTT.inputString[1];
          }else if((ReceivedMessageType==PUBACK)||(ReceivedMessageType==PUBCOMP)||(ReceivedMessageType==SUBACK)||(ReceivedMessageType==UNSUBACK)){
            int MessageID=MQTT.inputString[0]*256+MQTT.inputString[1];
          }else if(ReceivedMessageType==PINGREQ){
            MQTT.TCP_Flag=false;MQTT.pingFlag=false;MQTT.sendATreply("AT+CIPSHUT\r\n",".",4000);MQTT.modemStatus=0;
            Serial.println("Disconnecting");Serial.println("MQTT.TCP_Flag=False (ln261)");
          }
        }
      }else if((inChar==13)||(inChar==10)){Serial.print("inChar=13||10");}else{Serial.print("Received: Unknown Message Type: ");Serial.println(inChar);}
    }
  }
}
```

My Code is published at [pedromancuso/GSM_MQTT](https://github.com/pedromancuso/GSM_MQTT.git).

Suggestions?

Comment: Word of advice: your code is really hard to read. There's a reason most C programmers use a lot of whitespace and put statements on their own lines - it makes code much more readable. Readable code is easier to debug, especially when strangers are helping with the debugging. I'd strongly recommend running your code through a [C code formatter](https://codebeautify.org/c-formatter-beautifier). At the least, you're a lot more likely to get help from other people.

Comment: You are connecting to the SIM800 via Serial port lines....which will support SMS commands OR data commands, not both.  You might want to look more at the RI pin on the SIM800L so you can detect an SMS coming in and switch over to that and suspend any MQTT data traffic...if you really need to support both connection types.  https://img.filipeflop.com/files/download/Datasheet_SIM800L.pdf

Comment: JD Thank you so much. Excellent answer.

I think you are right, and, I'm actually using the RING PIN to detect incoming calls and it is detecting and working fine, but, when an incoming call is received, SIM800 can not handle "ATA" command as it is handling MQTT data traffic.

As you've said the option left is suspendind MQTT data traffic, how could i do so? I've tried sending "AT+CGATT=0" to detach from GPRS service, but it wont work.....Any suggestion?